# View element android

Tags: android, view, achartengine

I would like to show a chart that I create with GraphicalView from AChartEngineLibrary in another View element.
I should do that because I use the other view element to receive messages that I use to update the chart.
I don't know how to show a view element in aview element.
Can someone help me?
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
without third parties like AChartEngineLibrary also we will implement charts. below is the sample code for without third party this is the piechart example

package com.rmn.piechart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class AndroidPieChartActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    float values[]={200,400,200,500,300};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        values=calculateData(values);
        MyGraphview graphView = new MyGraphview(this, values);
        graphView.setPadding(50, 30, 35, 0);
        linear.addView(graphView,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    }
    private float[] calculateData(float[] data) {

        float total=0;
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            total+=data[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            data[i]=360*(data[i]/total);  
        }
        return data;

    }
    public class MyGraphview extends View
    {
        private Paint paint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        private float[] value_degree;
        private int[] COLORS={Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN,Color.GRAY,Color.CYAN,Color.RED};
        RectF rectf = new RectF (10, 10, 200, 200);
        int temp=0;
        public MyGraphview(Context context, float[] values) {
            super(context);
            value_degree=new float[values.length];
            for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++)
            {
                value_degree[i]=values[i];
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            for (int i = 0; i < value_degree.length; i++) {//values2.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
                    canvas.drawArc(rectf, 0, value_degree[i], true, paint);
                } 
                else
                {
                        temp += (int) value_degree[i - 1];
                        paint.setColor(COLORS[i]);
                        canvas.drawArc(rectf, temp, value_degree[i], true, paint);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```